# How to save web camera image with ID into wwwroot folder using dotnet core 3.1

Tags: c#

Please I need to assist me to solve a problem with save live web camera image into a wwwroot folder with Id of a staff. the code I'm used saving image from web camera with default filename but need to change to save with Id. below is the sample code.

```cs
var fileName = file.FileName;
var fileNameToStore = string.Concat(Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()), Path.GetExtension(fileName));
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\Photos", fileName);
var filepath = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "Photos") + $@"\{fileNameToStore}";

// Save image file in local folder
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
{
    using (FileStream fileStream = 
                 System.IO.File.Create(filepath))
    {
        file.CopyTo(fileStream);
        fileStream.Flush();
    }
 }
```

saved with: 03f59a92-65e0-4deb-80a4-b56e91d89d88.png
but I need to save like this: 10001.png

Comment: You somehow need to get the ID of the staff member who is saving the image (I imagine there is a `StaffService` or something like that somewhere) and replace the `Guid.NewGuid()` with said staff members ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
var fileNameToStore = string.Concat(Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()), Path.GetExtension(fileName));
```

with:

```
var fileNameToStore = string.Concat("10001", Path.GetExtension(fileName));
```

If you want to actually get the right ID at runtime you need some kind of data source for that. User Input? Windows Login? What data is available to you?

Comment: The problem was solved thank you very much, thanks once again.